# Nuget error when trying to publish in .Net5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publish, .net-5

When I publish in .Net5 I get the following Errors

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Assets file 'C:\Users\cornelis.dejager\source\repos\Marel.MSAWebServiceAPI\Marel.MSAWebServiceAPI\obj\publish\win-x86\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.    Marel.MSAWebServiceAPI      0

and

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x86' from remote source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.windowsdesktop.app.runtime.win-x86/index.json'.
> An error occurred while sending the request.
> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. Marel.MSAWebServiceAPI      0

### What caused it:

Not sure to be honest. After I changed code it stopped working. The project has been fine for weeks now and suddenly it changed.

### I have tried

- Cleaned solution
- Build/Re-Build Solution
- Restore The Nuget Packages
- Update Visual Studio
- Rebuild All projects
- Delete Bin & Object folders
- Update all packages
- Restarting Visual Studio + Computer
- Created new publishing profile
- install dotnet-WindowsDesktop
- Reinstall .Net5 Runtimes
- Run the command:

### Additional Info

- It builds and run fine. Only when I publish it seems to give me an error.

I really do not why publishing isn't working. I've looked at several places but have not found a solution to it yet.

Comment: Have you tried to clone project again on your own pc?

Comment: "After I changed code it stopped working", what did you change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may happen from the wrong package source,

In Visual Studio go to

> Options=> Nuget Package Manager=> Package Sources

if you are using a custom source make sure you have entered the address correctly.
NuGet default source address  is https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json